# How to coordinate 3 threads executing (UI done with DevExpress)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, devexpress

Here is my problem:

I have a Wcf service on a server that has two methods:

```
Synchronize() and GetExecutionState().
```

I also have a client that is to call those operations.

The Synchronize() executes lots of things and in several steps so at each step i update a local (inside the wcf) variable and i publish this variable via the GetExecutionState() operation The operation can fail, can take eons to execute and so on.

So, when i consume this service on the client, say on somebutton_click() event, 
what i want to happen is this:

- show infinite progressbar (main thread, UI);
- start a thread to run Synchronize();
- start another thread to keep reading  GetExecutionState() every x minutes and in the event of a connection failure (which is the main reason i need this last thread) cancel the whole thing.

I dont know lot about threading, but so far i have implemented 1 and 2. Can someone help me with 3?

I am using devExpress and here is my relevant code.

SERVER PART:

```
     public class SyncServerService :ISyncServer {

    protected CsNo Node;   
    protected SyncState State;

    public SyncServerService() {
        State = SyncState.None;
        Node = null;
    }       

    public SyncState OperationState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void PutComputerName(string value) {
        var man = new CsNoManager();
        Node = man.GetByMachineName(value);
    }        

    public bool CanSync() {  
        var man = new ViewSyncLogManager();
        var log = man.GetByMachineName(Node.MachineName);
        return !log[0].IsInSync;
    }

    public CommandExecutionResponse Synchronize() {

        CommandExecutionResponse res = null;

        var logManager = new CsLogSyncManager();
        var log = logManager.GetByNode(Node.IDNo);         
        State=SyncState.Syncing;
         //step 1
        State = SyncState.State2;
        //...step n
        State = SyncState.SomeOtherState;
        //somewhere along the path create the res object

        return res;
    } 
}
```

I read somewhere that with WCF, i can call operations both sync and async, so i dont think i have to mess with the server part regarding my requirements.

Client part:

On the button click that starts the process:

private void cmdSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

```
pgbSync.Properties.Stopped = false;

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

}

pgbSync is of type MarqueeProgressBar, a DevExpress progressbar that has infinite loop

backgroundWorker1 is of type System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker...supposedly runs tasks on the background.

It's start and finish methods are:

START:

```
private void StartSync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { 
            try {

                //setting up wcf link properties

                var manager = new CsConfiguracaoManager();
                var address = manager.SyncAppServiceAddress();
                var binding = new NetTcpBinding {
                    Security = new NetTcpSecurity() { Mode = SecurityMode.None },
                    CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0, 0),
                    OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0, 0),
                    ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0, 0),
                    SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0, 0)
                };

                var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISyncServer>(binding, new EndpointAddress(address));
                var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
                proxy.PutComputerName(PcName);

                //checking if i can sync first

                if (proxy.CanSync() == true) {
                    ExecutionResponse = proxy.Sync();
                }
                else {
                    //set up messages to show errors  
                }
            }
            catch (DataException dataErr) {
                //set up appropriate messages
            }
            catch (EndpointNotFoundException err) {
                //set up appropriate messages
            }
            catch (Exception masterErr) {
                //set up appropriate messages
            }
        }
```

FINISH:

private void FinishSync(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {

```
    pgbSync.Properties.Stopped = true;

    //process  ExecutionResponse object from FinishSync
}
```

This all runs, but if i disconnect the network after the process has started (we are anticipating lots of communication issues) the process will only throw an exception after the 30 minutes set in the service have passed.

Thats why i want to introduce a 3rd step where i check every x minutes for the output of OperationState.

If i cannot read it, i abort the operation, if it has a null or err state i also stop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am note sure if you need a 3rd thread for this.

Have you tried `System.Timers.Timer` to have an event generated every x seconds and doing your checks?

If that event does not occur you can go with a `BackgroundWorker` which will have a loop with `Thread.Sleep(250)` and cancelation checks.

Comment: I will try the Timers.Timer and come back to you